Performance Testing Ecommerce web application
I'm working on creating load test scripts for an e-commerce web application using JMeter. The application updates its requests based on the selected category. For example, selecting the Women's category displays subcategories like Tops, Bottoms, Jeans, Swimwear, etc.
Here’s my intended flow:

Access the main URL
Select the Women category
Choose the Tops sub category
Apply filters (e.g., size)
5.Select the first product from the displayed list

While recording this flow, I observed that when the Women category is selected in step 2, all GET requests for subcategories like Tops, Bottoms, Swimwear, etc., are captured. Similarly, selecting the Tops subcategory in step 3 results in GET requests for various Tops products. Thus, the GET requests depend on the chosen category/subcategory and the number of displayed products.
My question is how to modify this script to randomly select different categories (such as Women, Men, Kids) and subcategories (like Tops, Bottoms, Dresses) based on the chosen category.
Here’s an example of GET requests for a category and subcategory: mainURL/browse/category/423426002 and mainURL/browse/category/423426002/subcategory/5468790.
How can I adjust the script to include the Men category since all the current GET requests are for Women’s subcategories? Additionally, how can I determine which subcategory GET requests to make when a main category is selected?

Are you familiar with REST web services?

You need to use a suitable Post-Processor (in majority of cases for HTML it would be CSS Selector Extractor) and get the category IDs and eventually map them to category names.
Once done you can use i.e. Random Controller or Random Order Controller to choose this or that category randomly.
